# Probability - Counting techniques

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a hard time understanding counting problems and have no clue how to even start. Here is a problem that I am working on.

A family consisting of four persons—A, B, C, and D—belongs to a medical clinic that always has a doctor at each of stations 1, 2, and 3. During a certain week, each member of the family visits the clinic once and is assigned at random to a station. The experiment consists of recording the station number for each member. Suppose that any incoming individual is equally likely to be assigned to any of the three stations irrespective of where other individuals have been assigned.

(a) What is the probability that all four family members are assigned to the same station?

(b) What is the probability that at most three family members are assigned to the same station?

(c) What is the probability that one station has two family members at it and the others have only one?

Comment: Something is completely wrong in your question. In the description you mention **faculty members** and **review committee**. In the question itself, all of the sudden, they become **family members** and **station**. Also, you say that $2$ need to be selected, then you ask about the probability of selecting **all $4$**!!! Are you sure you didn't copy-paste in here two pieces of two different questions?

Comment: Oh wow, I'm way too tired to even copy paste. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

(a) $3\times\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^4$

(b) $1 - 3\times\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^4$

(c) $$ \frac{3{4\choose 2}\times2!}{3^4}$$

( Choose 2 members out of 4 and put them in 1 of the 3 three stations. Then, there are 2! ways to arrange the remaining 2 members)